# Convert normal mysql query with math functions into magento model format

Tags: database, collection, model, sql, query

I have the following query in MySQL. I need to convert it for `magento`.

My query is,

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, SQRT(
    POW(69.1 * (latitude - [startlat]), 2) +
    POW(69.1 * ([startlng] - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM TableName HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance;
```

I know how to use `addFieldToFilter()` for a single column and multi-column. but this is little confusing me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('model/alias_here')->getCollection();
$collection->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
    'distance',
    'SQRT(
     POW(69.1 * ({{latitude}} - [startlat]), 2) +
     POW(69.1 * ([startlng] - {{longitude}}) * COS({{latitude}} / 57.3), 2))',
    array('{{latitude}}' => 'latitude', 'longitude' => '{{longitude}}')
);
$collection->getSelect()->having('distance < 25');
$collection->setOrder('distance');
```

I don't understant what `[startlat]` and `[startlng]` are, but I assume they are some fixed values.

Comment: [startlat] and [startlng] both are start point of latitude and longitude

Comment: $collection->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
    'distance',
    'SQRT(
     POW(69.1 * (latitude - 44), 2) +
     POW(69.1 * ((-74) - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2))'
);
$collection->getSelect()->having('distance < 25');

This one is working for me